# BIN$ tables without "recycle bin"

Tags: oracle

My Oracle Database (10.2) contains tables in Form "BIN$". They are listed by

```
select * from user_recyclebin
```

but not by

```
show recycle_bin
```

The command "show parameters" indicate "recyclebin=on" (it is also the default value in Oracle).

Moreover: Oracle put a table in the recycle bin only if it is member of a cluster, isn't it? (I understand the Oracle Administrator Guide so...). I indeed have dropped the corresponding tables, but I never have used any cluster in this database...

A call to PURGE TABLE has worked: the entry disappeared of user_recyclebin. But why did I have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I didn't understand the SQL statement reference first:

> If you drop a table that is part of a cluster, the table is moved to the recycle bin. However, if you subsequently drop the cluster, then the table is purged from the recycle bin and can no longer be recovered with a FLASHBACK TABLE operation.

All tables are put in the bin, the normal ones as well as the cluster ones. The difference is, that the recycle tables of a cluster disapper if the cluster is dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Dropped tables go to the recyclebin *except* for members of a cluster!

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tables.htm#ADMIN01511

How did you drop your tables?

The command

```
drop table x;
```

will cause the table to be moved to the recyclebin, while

```
drop table x purge;
```

will cause the table to be dropped immediately.

Comment: drop table x, without purge. But it wasn't member of a cluster... and <pre>
SQL> drop table x, without purge. But it wasn't member of a cluster... and <pre>SQL>create table test (id number);
SQL> insert into test values (1);
SQL> commit;
SQL> drop table test;
</pre> didn't add (this time) the table im recycle bin...

Comment: Updated answer: all dropped tables *except* members of a cluster go to the recyclebin.